# Runge Kutta method in python

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta

These are the functions I have written:

```
def rk4(f, t0, y0, h, N):
    t = t0 + arange(N+1)*h
    y = zeros((N+1, size(y0)))
    y[0] = y0
    for n in range(N):
        xi1 = y[n]
        f1 = f(t[n], xi1)
        xi2 = y[n] + (h/2.)*f1
        f2 = f(t[n+1], xi2)
        xi3 = y[n] + (h/2.)*f2
        f3 = f(t[n+1], xi3)
        xi4 = y[n] + h*f3
        f4 = f(t[n+1], xi4)
        y[n+1] = y[n] + (h/6.)*(f1 + 2*f2 + 2*f3 + f4)
    return y

def lorenzPlot():
    y = rk4(fLorenz, 0, array([0,2,20]), .01, 10000)
    fig = figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.plot(*y.T)

def fLorenz(t,Y):   
    def Y(x,y,z):
        return array([10*(y-x), x*(28-z)-y, x*y-(8./3.)*z])
```

By implementing lorenzPlot, it's supposed to graph the numerical solution to fLorenz (the Lorenz system of equations) obtained using rk4 (4th order Runge Kutta method).  I'm having a problem with the function fLorenz.  When I define it as above and call lorenzPlot, I get an error that says

```
File "C:/...", line 38, in rk4
    xi2 = y[n] + (h/2.)*f1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I guessed that this had something to do with not being able to multiply the array correctly.
However, when I changed fLorenz to

```
def fLorenz(t,x,y,z):   
    return array([10*(y-x), x*(28-z)-y, x*y-(8./3.)*z])
```

calling lorenzPlot gives me the error stating that fLorenz takes 4 arguments, but only 2 are given.

Additionally, rk4 and lorenzPlot both work correctly for functions composed of a singular equation.

How should I change fLorenz so that it can be used as f in rk4 and lorenzPlot?

Answer (score 2):

Your first `fLorenz` function defines a sub-function, but doesn't actually return anything. Your second one does, except it's expecting four arguments (`t, x, y, z`), and you only give it `t, Y`.

From what I can understand, `Y` is a three-tuple; you can simply unpack it before you use the values:

```
def fLorenz(t, Y):
    x, y, z = Y
    return array([10*(y-x), x*(28-z)-y, x*y-(8./3.)*z])
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't mention it above because I assumed it couldn't possibly be right, but previously I tried Y = x, y, z as the second line.  This makes a lot more sense, thanks

Comment: No problem! I should add as a concern - I don't see the value of `t` actually being used anywhere, which seems alarming.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fLorenz` doesn't return anything, i.e., due to the well documented Python conventions, it returns `None`.

Your error message tells you

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

and that the error happens in the statement

```
    xi2 = y[n] + (h/2.)*f1
```

In the previous line you assigned to `f1` what is returned by an invocation of `fLorenz`, i.e., `None`.

If you change the function `fLorenz` so that it returns a numerical value, either scalar or array, maybe you can proceed with your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the implementation errors, your understanding of the RK4 method is incomplete. The evaluation of the midpoint slopes has to happen at the midpoint of all components, which includes the time component. Thus it should be `t[n]+h/2` instead of `t[n+1]` in the evaluation of `f2` and `f3`.